# Finding $\lim_{x \to \pi/2} \tan^2 x$.

Tags: calculus, limits

Finding $\lim_{x \to \pi/2} \tan^2 x$.

Is it just does not exist as  $\lim_{x \to \pi/2} \tan x$?

Comment: What have you tried? What is the limit for the (unsquared) tan function?

Comment: @JTP-ApologisetoMonica it does not exists as it is $-\infty$ from one side and $\infty$ from the other side ..... am I correct?

Comment: Also, I think I am writing my trial.@JTP-ApologisetoMonica

Comment: Exactly…… that’s the process here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit, if taken only from one of the two sides, is either negative infinity or infinity if the tangent is not squared. But the function is squared. Hence the limit you gave is positive infinity.

Comment: Technically, though, saying it is $\infty$ is a way of saying the limit does not exist.

Comment: Saying that it does not exist is not as accurate as giving the exact expression. Take $f(x) = e^{x}$ for when the variable is smaller than $0$ and $f(x)= e^{-x}-2$ if $x>0$. Now the limit as the variable approaches $0$ does not exist not because of the function's output becoming arbitrarily big or small.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with that. The point is that the intuition that OP has is that the limit does not exist, and that intuition is correct. As to why it is correct, that is covered in your answer, but I think this clarification is needed, hence my comment. It is not meant to take away from your answer, but to add to it.

Comment: If the user asked if this limit does not exist "just like" some other limit, then I think it is reasonable to assume they have intuitively conjectured to themselves that the limit really does not exist, but are unsure of their answers. Clarification is typically the purpose of such answers, hence my statement that there is an intuition there is an inference based on this. I can understand how the phrasing "just like" could be taken to mean what you suggested, though, but that really boils down to semantics, and your answer already covers that.